# Why Windows 8 is summing files only if they less than 100 files, and how can this number be increased?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, statusbar

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I noticed that when I select less than 100 files, I can see their total size on the status bar.

[image]

but if I select 100 files (and more), I need to open files' properties in order to see their total size.

[image]

Can I configure Win 8.1 so it will display the total size of more than 100 files?

Comment: No; You can't change this behavior unless you replace the explorer shell.

Comment: How do you know that there is no key for that in the registry which can be modified? There are so many parameters of Expolrer that can be modified, I believe it should be somewhere

Comment: I base my statement based on 15 years of experience working with Windows.